# Apache Mono - 503 Error

Tags: mono, mod-mono

When I access my site I see the Mono icon, but trying to access any page gives 503 error - "Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Here is near the end of my httpd.conf (IP addresses hidden):

---

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf/mod_mono.conf
<VirtualHost *.80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName 74.63.???.?
</VirtualHost>
```

---

And here is my mod_mono.conf

---

```
<IfModule !mod_mono.c>
LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so.0.0.0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Powered-By "Mono"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mono_module>

AddType application/x-asp-net .aspx
....
DirectoryIndex index.aspx

MonoAutoApplication enabled
MonoDebug false
MonoServerPath "/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/mod-mono-server4/2.10.2.0__032efab45532/mod-mono-server4
Alias /test "/opt/monoserv"
MonoApplications "/test:/opt/monoserv"
SetHandler mono

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: New to this myself but I've recently found that a close inspection of the Apache error log will reveal a lot of mono stuff. On my installation this is in /var/log/apache2/error.log.  Also my MonoServerPath points to a shell script /usr/local/bin/mod-mono-server4 which, in turn, calls 'exec /usr/local/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@" '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks shunty for the help. I looked at the logs and it said "Failed to connect to mod-mono-server after several attempts to spawn the process."

I changed the MonoServerPath to point to the example in shunty's comment, and changed the paths found in that file to correct ones.

Then I followed the instructions here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?524548-RESOLVED-mod_mono-with-apache

I still have problems, but at least they aren't related to server configuration anymore. Thanks!